# Scriptural references and significance of the Lotus symbol on the thumb

Tags: scripture, astrology, body, symbols, lotus

In studying Samudrika Shastra, an important part of Hindu scriptures, I've learned that certain signs or symbols on the body bear significant importance. A recurring symbol I've come across in various discussions is the **lotus symbol on the thumb**. While many online sources mention it, and sufficiently elaborate on its symbolic significance, they often lack authentic scriptural references. The 'Thumb' and the 'lotus' have stood out as symbols of interest, given their individual significance in palmistry and Hindu spiritual traditions respectively.

Could anyone provide authoritative references from Hindu scriptures that mention this lotus symbol on the thumb? I'm particularly interested in understanding the symbolic meaning or significance it carries. If there are any people in scriptures that have the lotus on the thumb, please mention their names and the role of having lotus symbol on thumb, if needed.

Comment: This is a question about astrology, not hinduism.

Comment: And Astrology is part of Hinduism @SwamiVishwananda